# Utilising the same one value for different variables

Tags: modeling

my smart friends! I have a little question, is it possible to set one parameter, one value anywhere in Blender and use it many times for the different purpose. For example, how it looks: I set parameter Parme1=1 and the use the same Param1 for value X, Y or  Z of any origin of any object, or for Decimation, or for Scale or for any other purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a custom property in your scene or your world, and use it to drive your transforms with the "Copy as new driver" and "Paste Driver" operators.

[image]

You can then edit the way the property is used by right clicking in the driven field choose "Edit Driver", and then "Scripted expression". You can use standard python expressions. Here we multiply the property by 2 :

[image]

Comment: Awesome, it is exactly what I want! Thanks!